# OpenMeetings clustering not wok

Tags: openmeetings

Does any one know to get OpenMeetings clustering wok?

I try it with the guide in page http://openmeetings.apache.org/Clustering.html ,not working

with the guide in page http://openmeetings.apache.org/Clustering.html , I setup two server for clustering  testing , and  It did not work. I find some log  as the follow,  is it about job-store?How should I config it?

> org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data
>   : Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.0) 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFact
>   oryBean#0' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
>   Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
>   NOT STARTED.
>   Currently in standby mode.
>   Number of jobs executed: 0
>   Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
>   Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persis
>   tence. and is not clustered.

Answer (score 0):

This question was also asked at Apache OpenMeeting JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENMEETINGS-2097

The problem seems to be resolved after correct Hazelcast config was created